# dotnet core app not working well reserve proxy nginx

Tags: nginx, model-view-controller, .net-core

I published my dotnet mvc app to linux. My app doesn't work stable. Login page can load correctly but when I try to reload page , I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Here is nginx error log:

*217 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.130.17, server: 
 *217 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.130.17, server: 
 *217 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, client: 192.168.130.17, server: , request: 
*219 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, client: 192.168.130.17, server: , request:

I tried to change timeout values.
I tried to change nginx configuration.

Here is my nginx default config:

```
server {
 listen 80;
# listen [::]:80;
 allow 127.0.0.1;
 location / {
 proxy_read_timeout 300;
 proxy_connect_timeout 300;
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 client_max_body_size 10m;
 client_body_buffer_size 128k;
 proxy_send_timeout 90;
 proxy_buffers 32 4k;
 }
}

upstream dotnet {
    zone dotnet 64k;
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

Here is my dotnet app code for reserve proxy :

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions{              ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across same problem few days back.
In my case, the reason was less buffer sizes in Kubernetes configuration file.
Try increasing buffer sizes to following -

```
http{
...
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
...
}
```

For more detailed answer, please refer following link -

https://medium.com/@mshanak/solve-nginx-error-signin-oidc-502-bad-gateway-dotnet-core-and-identity-serve-bc27920b42d5

Hope this resolves your issue!

Comment: Thank you Aparna but it doesn't work for me. Then I try to use Apache as a proxy server but it doesn't stabil too. Because of this error : warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Connection processing ended abnormally.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (125): Operation canceled
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0(SocketError e)